# Javascript how to pass response back to client using async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, response

I want to send back the JSON response to the client. Since I am new to Javascript I do not know how can I do this. Please see my code below

```
 async pay(data) {



    stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: data.customerID,
      items: [{ plan: data.plan }],
      function(err, cards) {
        // asynchronously called
        res.json(cards);
        console.log('this is the customer cards', res);
      },
    });
  
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any error doing this?

Comment: you code seems about right if you are using it under a context which has the ``res`` http variable.. can you see your console and show us the error?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting "cannot find name 'res'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see you pasing any variable named `res` into the *callback function* you call with arguments `err` and `cards`. I guess you need to get it into it probably as an argument. Be sure about the parameters signature of that from its docs. Maybe it has another parameter for `res`, or maybe the seconds parameter is the `res`.

As [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node) states you get a `subscription` object from that api call. And it is passed as the second parameter to the callback funciton you use. You should be able to use it directly since it says it is an object. If it was a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object you would need to use the [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) method as you have done but I think that is not the case.

So:

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');
var result;
stripe.subscriptions.create(
  {
    customer: 'cus_HmesysP1Ayztet',
    items: [
      {price: 'price_1HD1XM2eZvKYlo2CVQMCC4qb'},
    ],
  },
  function(err, subscription) {
    // asynchronously called
    // use subscription object directly.
    console.log("subscription: ", subscription);
    result = subscription;
  }
);
```

If you want to assign it to another variable visible outside of the callback, declare that variable outside, like before `stripe.subscriptions.create` call and then assign inside like `result = subscription` inside the callback. You do not have to call it subscription you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: @jack Have you tried this idea? Does that idea work for you?

Comment: i tried var res; and then res = cards; but didn't work

Comment: I do not think passing an argument to .json method will work.